# How to clear VS2013 MSDN cloud-cached settings?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-10, msdn

I have recently had an office 2016 click to run update land on my windows 10 machine (VS 2013 Pro/2015/2019 installed).

*All* c# builds (*NOT VB/C++*) for all project types in VS 2013 have failed instantly *with no output errors in the VS output window*.  (Can't upgrade my projects/solutions to 2015/17/19 due to certain deprecated 3rd party dependencies in 2015 onwards - but VS2015/2019 builds ok for other projects)
NB: MSBuild works just fine in isolation at command line with no build errors.
NB2: locating the MSIs that came down and uninstalling their updates doesn't fix anything (as per instructions here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_install-mso_win10/office-16-click-to-run-extensibility-component-64/e79ee5bd-f119-4808-9bb2-289dd815b76a)

A colleague can login to my machine, load up VS 2013 and build a simple hello world console app with no errors. 
I login to their machine (hadnt done this before: so there was no cached profile), open exact same version/build/updates of VS 2013 there (makes me login to MSDN to sync settings), and once MSDN has done its setting sync I cannot build. (MSBuild works fine)

My IT guys have AD roaming profiles disabled; so it cant be my windows profile. The only thing that really can be common is the MSDN/VS2013 settings downloaded from my MSDN profile itself.

Is there a way to clear out my VS2013 saved settings from directly within my MSDN account?

NB: we have about 100 devs, and 2 of us have received the exact same updates on the same day (nobody else did), and we are experiencing the exact same issue.

Comment: Turn on detailed compiler logging in VS options.  See what it has to say.

Comment: Also, launch VS using `/log`.  [Details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/log-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2013), then inspect Visual Studio's log.  see if it contains any clues.